# Does iOS support TLS compression?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, compression, ssl

I need to compress data sent over a secure channel in my iOS app and I was wondering if I could use [TLS compression](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3749) for the same. I am unable to figure out if Apple's TLS implementation, Secure Transport, supports the same.

Does anyone else know if TLS compression is supported in iOS or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to determine if Apple implementation of SSL/TLS did support compression, but I have to say that I am afraid it does not.

At first I was hopeful that having a `errSSLPeerDecompressFail` error code, there has to be a way to enable the compression. But I could not find it.

The first obvious reason that Apple doesn’t support compression is several wire captures I did from my device (6.1) opening secure sockets in different ports. In all of them the Client Hello packet reported only one compression method: `null`.

Then I looked at the last available code for [`libsecurity_ssl`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-55003) available from Apple. This is the implementation from Mac OS X 10.7.5, but something tells me that the iOS one will be very similar, if not the same, but surely it will not be more powerful than the Mac OS X one.

You can find in the file [`sslHandshakeHello.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-55003/lib/sslHandshakeHello.c), lines 186-187 (`SSLProcessServerHello`):

```
if (*p++ != 0)      /* Compression */
    return unimpErr;
```

That error code sounds a lot like “if the server sends another compression but `null` (0), we don’t implement that, so fail”.

Again, the same file, line 325 (`SSLEncodeClientHello`):

```
*p++ = 0; /* null compression */
```

And nothing else around (`DEFLATE` is the method 1, according to RFC 3749).

Below, lines 469, 476 and 482-483 (`SSLProcessClientHello`):

```
compressionCount = *(charPtr++);
...
/* Ignore list; we're doing null */
...
/* skip compression list */
charPtr += compressionCount;
```

I think it is pretty clear that this implementation only handles the `null` compression: it is the only one sent in the Client Hello, the only one understood in the Server Hello, and the compression methods are ignored when the Client Hello is received (`null` must be implemented and offered by every client).

So I think both you and me have to implement an application level compression. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this!